# What do two colons mean in PHP?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I don't know what it's doing when we have this situation:

```
Foo::Bar
```

It looks like a path.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That's (generally) for accessing a static method or property in a class. It's called the scope resolution operator, or Paamayim Nekudotayim (which leads to some amazingly confusing error messages!). See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php.

Comment: You beat me to it ;) Removed my answer as duplicate post.

Comment: As the PHP manual page above notes, it means "double colon" Hebrew. Wikipedia mentions it, too. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator#PHP

Comment: I think I'll stick with calling it the double colon.

Answer (score 54):

The [`::` operator is the scope resolution operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php). It is used to access class constants or static properties and methods, either from outside the class:

```
ClassName::CONSTANT_VALUE
ClassName::staticMethod()
```

Or within a class method to reference the same or a parent class using `self` and `parent`:

```
self::CONSTANT_VALUE
self::staticMethod()
parent::CONSTANT_VALUE
parent::staticMethod()
```

Comment: and static:: we can use

Comment: That's true. I suggested `static::CONSTANT_VALUE`, `static::staticMethod()`

Answer (score 6):

The Scope Resolution Operator(::)the double colon, is a token that allows access to **static**, **constant**, and overridden properties or methods of a class.

```
<?php
class A {

public static $B = '1'; # Static class variable.

const B = '2'; # Class constant.

public static function B() { # Static class function.
    return '3';
}

}

echo A::$B . A::B . A::B(); # Outputs: 123
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

To supplement the answers regarding PHP's use of two colons as its ["scope resolution operator"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php):

In addition, a double colon is used:

1. To resolve an unqualified, qualified, or aliased class name to its fully qualified form, and
2. To invoke a class's "__callStatic" method with an arbitrary, previously undeclared method name.

## To resolve a class name to its fully qualified form by appending "::class"

Two colons followed by the "class" keyword, placed after the name of a class, provides that class's fully qualified name as a string.  *I.e.*,  "ClassName::class" resolves to the fully qualified name of "ClassName".  *See*:  (A) [Manual: Classes and Objects: Basics](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php), (B)  [Manual: Classes and Objects: Class Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php), and (C) [Manual: Language Reference: Constants](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

The syntax was adopted in PHP 5.5.  *See*: (A) [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/class_name_scalars) and (B) [PHP 5.5 New Features](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php)

The "::class" syntax is useful within a namespace to obtain the fully qualified name of a class from its [unqualified or qualified form](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php), or from an [alias](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) of its name.

The "::class" syntax seems to work to resolve interface names as well as class names, although that does not appear to be documented by the sources linked above.

Within a class, the syntax also works with "self::class", as mentioned by the "::class" RFC linked above.

A few examples:

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace;

use MyNamespace\YourInterface as HerInterface;    
use MyNamespace\YourClass as HerClass;
use MyNamespace\TheirClass as OurClass;

interface MyInterface { }

interface YourInterface { }

class MyClass { }

class YourClass { }

class TheirClass
{
    public function fullName()
    {
        echo self::class;
    }
}

$ourClassInstance = new OurClass;

echo MyClass::class, PHP_EOL;
// outputs: MyNamespace\MyClass

echo HerClass::class, PHP_EOL;
// outputs: MyNamespace\YourClass

echo MyInterface::class, PHP_EOL;
// outputs: MyNamespace\MyInterface

echo HerInterface::class, PHP_EOL;
// outputs: MyNamespace\YourInterface

echo $ourClassInstance->fullName(), PHP_EOL;
// outputs: MyNamespace\TheirClass
```

## To invoke "__callStatic" with an undeclared method name

Two colons can be used to "call" a static method name that a class has not declared.  E.g., "ClassName::arbitraryMethodName()". Doing so invokes the class's "__callStatic" method, if the class has declared one.  It also passes to __callStatic the name of the undeclared method and any arguments passed to the undeclared method.  The __callStatic method then may "dynamically" choose how to handle the call.  PHP refers to this as ["overloading"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) with the [__callStatic "magic method"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).

See additional [StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840911/callstatic-instantiating-objects-from-static-context)

Example:

```
<?php

namespace OurCompany\Orders;

class Intake
{
    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        $item = substr($name, 5); // trims "order" prefix

        $specialistClass = "\OurCompany\Specialists\\" . $item;

        if (class_exists($specialistClass)) {
            $specialist = new $specialistClass;
            return $specialist->handleOrder($arguments);
        }

        return "I'm sorry, we can't help you with " .
            lcfirst($item) . ".";
    }
}

namespace OurCompany\Specialists;

class Car
{
    public function handleOrder($arguments)
    {
        return "May I help you with a $arguments[0] car?";
    }
}

class Truck
{
    public function handleOrder($arguments)
    {
        return "May I help you with a $arguments[0] truck?";
    }
}

use OurCompany\Orders\Intake;

echo Intake::orderCar("red"), PHP_EOL;
// outputs: May I help you with a red car?

echo Intake::orderTruck("pickup"), PHP_EOL;
// outputs: May I help you with a pickup truck?

echo Intake::orderShoes("suede"), PHP_EOL;
// outputs: I'm sorry, we can't help you with shoes.
```

Comment: As of PHP 8.1 we can also `use ::class` on variables: `echo $ourClassInstance::class, PHP_EOL;` 

Answer (score 0):

use of Scope Resolution Operator

> A class constant,  class property (static),   class function (static)
>   can all share the same name and be accessed using the double-colon

```
class B{
    public static $par = "par";
}
class A extends B{
    const B = "constant";
    public static $sel = "self";

    public static $b = "static property";
    public static function b(){
        echo "static function";
    }
    public static function c(){
        return parent::$par;
    }
    public static function d(){
        return self::$sel;
    }
     public static function e(){
        return self::$par;
    }
}

echo A::B.PHP_EOL;
echo A::$b.PHP_EOL;
echo A::b().PHP_EOL;
echo A::c().PHP_EOL;
echo A::d().PHP_EOL;
```